# How do you make the Material UI drawer scroll with the page rather than inside the drawer?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have implemented the material UI Drawer as per the responsive example on Material UI's website. On larger screens, how do I get the drawer to scroll with the whole page? At the moment, if the contents of the drawer become too long, a vertical scroll bar appears on the drawer itself which I o KY want to happen on smaller devices.

Here is a link to the code on Material UI's site:
https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#responsive-drawer

I have tried overflow: hidden but obviously the contents then cut off and hide the content!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because you specify `height` in your styles... Remove it or make it `auto`. It's a long shot, you should provide your `css` :)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I'll give your suggestion a go. The CSS I used is the same as in the link above. The scrollbar seems to be a feature within the Material UI components that I would like to override.